# How to obtain smooth and sharp silicone line on rough tiles?

Tags: silicone

How can I obtain sharp silicone caulking when the walls are tiled with small tiles, with a rough texture? I used a silicone profiling tool, but I did not try spraying soapy water before profiling. The difficulty I have is that as I apply pressure and push the profiling tool into the corner, the rough textured tiles are preventing me from moving the tool smoothly and steadily.

I attached a photo where you can see the end result. There are three issues I would like to solve:

- the silicone line is jagged and shaky;
- there is quite a bit of excess silicone (edges are not sharp);
- and grout transitions are noticeable.

[image: Silicone is jagged and ugly]

Comment: Getting smooth caulk lines is as much art as it is science. Practice. A lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a softer caulking knife.  There are cheap silicone caulking sets on line.  Buy one and try the different shapes.  You want the corners of the tool to bounce up and down with the bumps but because they are so soft they do not carry the whole tool with them; so long as you apply just the right pressure.   Just using your finger might work nicely, try it.  Either way, a lot of practice will help.